# how to make a design in an image in such a way that the captions should not get wrapped?

Tags: gui-design, ux-field, ux-designer, human-interface-guideline

In the image below, [image] how can i make the right side structure fit into the 40% of the aligned area such that the captions above the dropdown and delete icon should not get wrapped?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to defy the laws of physics here. '*How can I make something that is too large for its container, fit into that container*'? I would suggest if your layout can't accomodate the content then you should address the entire layout option itself, not the content.

Comment: Are you looking for an implementation solution? ("How do I set text to no-wrap?") This isn't the right forum for that kind of questions.

Comment: The question is clearly about "making a design", and JonW's comment nails it. The answer is to create more space for the labels. Or change the make the font-size: 2px  : )

Comment: Also if your content allows, try not to use selects where it is possible to replace with another input type (true / false -> checkbox, etc.)

Comment: Based on the comment given to the answer by sgtfrankieboy, I suggest that the question written above is not necessarily the right question.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to rotate the labels at an angle. This is done sometimes with charts when the labels do not fit.

Like in this example:

[image: An example of a graph with rotated labels]

Comment: so then, can i get sugessions about how can i design for this kind?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your immediate question, you might consider rotating text at an angle. Here is a great online resource I use often. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/

The layout you are attempting may not be a good strategy. Without more explanation related to the use case of this form and the importance of the collapsable sections to the left it is difficult to be more helpful. I recommend using the the full-width of the form above or below the collapsable section content to the left and that will allow more usable space for the labels and the dropdownlist below.

If the right content with the label issue is not something that must be displayed all of the time, you may consider a left-side modal.

Hope this is helpful!